# Cordova crosswalk native platform doesn't recognized by play store

Tags: android, cordova, android-ndk, crosswalk-runtime

I use cordova 5.1.1 with crosswalk webview for my app project, and after I build with key signing it properly shows two different files for x86 and arm build. The problem is when uploading to google play store, the dev dashboard detect arm64-v8a, armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86, and x86_64 as its native platforms, for both files.

It confuses me as the guide below shows that they should give the proper native platform.

https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/9a/72/Intel_Walkthrough_GP-Multiple_APK_Submissions.pdf

Do I have to use Intel XDK build? I prefer not to use it since all my files are already working locally and it's a big hassle to migrate to XDK build.

My other suspicion is that I'm missing NDK support for Android studio, I tried to install NDK bundle, but the problem persist.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you list all the files that are inside your APK, under `lib/` ? (Open your APKs as zip files). Something looks wrong here.

Comment: I checked that `lib` folder and found out what causing this. Thank you very much @ph0b !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked my APK lib directory as suggested by ph0b, and this was listed inside:

```
lib/
+-- arm64-v8a/
    +-- libsqlc-native-driver.so
+-- armeabi/
    +-- libsqlc-native-driver.so
+-- armeabi-v7a/
    +-- libsqlc-native-driver.so
    +-- libxwalkcore.so
+-- x86/
    +-- libsqlc-native-driver.so
+-- x86_64/
    +-- libsqlc-native-driver.so
```

Apparently another sqlite plugin is adding their own lib on my build and messes up with the target native platform.

Comment: I have this exact issue also. Is there a solution you've found that keeps the build automated using the cordova cli tool?